# Can use command prompt for wpr

Tags: windows, operating-system, command-prompt, wpa, wpr

I have just downloaded Windows Performance Recorder.
In the command prompt (running as administrator), I can type:

wpr -start CPU

or

wpr -start GPU

and it works perfectly.

But when I want to trace USB by typing

wpr -start USB

or

wpr -start USBTrace

I have the error: The system cannot find the file secifiied.
I reinstalled the wpr with all services checked in the installer, still not working.

Comment: GPU and CPU are buildin profiles, so they work (run **wpr -profiles** to see all buildin ones)  For your selfmade profiles use the fullpath to the wprp file.